# uiwebview crashes because of Cache,how can i remove UIwebview Cache?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

uiwebview crashes because of Cache,how can i remove UIwebview Cache?please if anyone know then kindly help

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
headingLabel.text= @"Crop Browser";
spinner.hidden= true;
webview.hidden= false;
closeButton.hidden=YES;

NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
[sharedCache release];
sharedCache = nil;
// remove all cached responses
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

// set an empty cache


NSLog(@"webfinish");
if(cropButton.tag!=1)   //1 would mean the crop button is hidden manually (user pressed crop button)
    cropButton.hidden= false;
}
```

Comment: _'uiwebview crashes because of Cache'_ how do you know? What does your stack trace look like? What appears on the console when it crashes?

Comment: because when i browse more the app crash.if i just stay on the google page then app never crashed

Comment: Well, that could be anything! What does your stack trace / console look like when you've crashed?

Comment: i am actually taking the picture from webview and use it in my controller and when i am keep on doing this process again and again then my app crashes with no information in console